# C++17 unique_ptr lambda capture by value is ok, but not by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have make a program showing that passing by value is fine but passing by reference will trigger SEGMENT FAULT.

Currently, there are two `unique_ptr` maker functions as `new_unique_ptr` and `new_unique_ptr2` as follows

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <class T, class Deleter>
unique_ptr<T, function<void(T *)>> new_unique_ptr(T *ptr, Deleter d) {
  return unique_ptr<T, function<void(T *)>>(ptr, [&](auto v) {
    if (v) {
      d(v);
    }
  });
}

template <class T, class Deleter>
unique_ptr<T, function<void(T *)>> new_unique_ptr2(T *ptr, Deleter d) {
  return unique_ptr<T, function<void(T *)>>(ptr, [=](auto v) {
    if (v) {
      d(v);
    }
  });
}

void free_int(int *v) { delete v; }

int main() {
  printf("0: %p\n", free_int);

  {
    printf("\n--- demo1 ---\n");

    auto v2 = new_unique_ptr2(new int(2), free_int);
    printf("value is %d\n", *v2);
  }

  {
    printf("\n--- demo2 ---\n");
    auto v = new_unique_ptr(new int(1), free_int);

    printf("value is %d\n", *v);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run

```sh
g++ main.cc

./a.out
```

will show sample output as

```sh
0: 0x7f99c7efe209

--- demo1 ---
11: 0x7f99c7efe209
value is 2
22: 0x7f99c7efe209

--- demo2 ---
1: 0x7f99c7efe209
value is 1
2: 0x7fff3e5ae7e0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

which indicates the passed by reference demo (`demo2`) failed.

Really appreciate if someone could help explaining why~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `new_unique_ptr` the lambda is capturing the function parameter `d` by-reference; `d` will be destroyed when `new_unique_ptr` returns, left the captured reference dangled. After that when the `std::unique_ptr` gets destroyed, the deleter is called on the dangling reference which leads to UB.